# is there a way to define a recursive __repr__ for a class that contains itself?

Tags: python, repr

Let's say that I have a class:

```
class Band():
    def __init__(self, name, members):
        self.name = name
        self.members = members

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'''{self.name} [{', '.join(self.members)}]'''
```

If I create two instances of it like this:

```
Band_A = Band('Band A', ['Tom', 'Josh'])
Band_B = Band('Band B', ['Mark', 'Steve'])
```

When I print them, I get the expected result:

```
Band A [Tom, Josh]
Band B [Mark, Steve]
```

But when I create an instance of the class that contains itself, then it doesn't work.

```
Band_C = Band('Band C', [Band_A, Band_B])
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/IcyTear/Desktop/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(Band_C)
  File "c:/Users/IcyTear/Desktop/test.py", line 7, in __repr__
    return f'''{self.name} [{', '.join(self.members)}]'''
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Band found
```

Is there a way to make it work so it displays this?

```
Band C [Band A [Tom, Josh], Band B [Mark, Steve]]
```

Comment: `', '.join` expects its argument to be an iterable of _strings_

Comment: You have to join the `repr()`s of the members.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `__repr__(self)` to

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'''{self.name} [{', '.join(map(repr, self.members))}]'''
```

to get

```
Band C [Band A [Tom, Josh], Band B [Mark, Steve]]
```

`str.join()` want an iterable of string, so explicitly convert every `member` into its string representation using `map(repr, ...)`